# ETA on Smart Device Projects for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I really want to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010.   But since I do a lot of development for the Pocket PC version of Windows Mobile I cannot.  (I develop for a Symbol device that does not support Windows Phone 7, so that is not a option.)

Does any one know any kind of time frame of when Microsoft plans to add support for Smart Device Projects into Visual Studio 2010?

**Update: Since this is looking less and less likely without intervention from the users, Please go [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010?wa=wsignin1.0) and vote for this feature.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft's [current public statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t(VS.100).aspx) says that, apart from Windows Phone 7 development, there will not be Smart Device Application Development added to Visual Studio 2010.

This obviously raises concerns and has implications for a lot of people, and there are more than a few of us lobbying Microsoft very hard to change that plan and to get them to include some sort of support for Smart Device programming outside of Windows Phone.

I'm hopeful, maybe even optimistic, that their stance will change and that we will get something - even if it's only CF 3.5 targeting actual hardware (i.e. no emulator support) - at some point down the road.  Right now they've got all hands on deck trying to get Windows Phone out the door, and until that happens, I wouldn't expect much for resource allocation toward other device features.

So what does that actually mean?  In my mind I wouldn't postpone installing VS2010 until they have device support.  My guess is it won't happen until early next year at the absolute earliest and realistically I would say mid to late next year *if it happens at all*.  Again, I'm optimistic that it will, but I'm also a realist, so I'm not going to base my business decisions and future on it happening.

Comment: Ouch!  Not what I wanted to hear, but at least I know now.  I have to say I am frustrated by this, but not surprised.  As a phone Windows Mobile is very weak.  I have found it decent for mobile application development (though I admittedly have only old Palm Pilot experience to compare to).  It does make me a little mad that MS is planning to leave us behind like this.  I have a app that I am about to roll out on Symbol Devices running Windows Mobile.  To think that I will have to support it in VS 2008 from now on makes me feel as if it has already been given the title of "Legacy".

Comment: Do you have any link or way to get to that public statement?  (So I can pass it on to the higher ups at my company.)

Comment: I've added a link to the answer.

Comment: The more I think about this the more upset it gets me.  I posted a comment on that announcement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t%28VS.100%29.aspx#21), but I know MS does not read that kind of stuff.  How are you "lobbying" MS to change their plan?  If it is something that a normal developer like me can participate in, I would like to.

Comment: Because I've been doing CF development for so long and have been an MVP for a decade, I know people that I, and several other MVPs are hoping can help explain the situation to and influence the people who actually make these strategic decisions.

As far as how the general developer can help, I don't know.  Maybe we could start a public petition, though how much weight it would carry I can't say.

Answer (score 3):

Add your support to the following Microsoft Connect Item, it's had quite a bit of interest being the 3rd highest voted suggestion so far.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010

Through private conversations I've had with the Customer Advocacy Team at MS it would appear that they are really digging their heels in over this.  MS reneged on promises to include Smart Device Framework support in VS2010 early on in the product life cycle.

It is really frustrating because at some point the development tools will fragment and you'll end up with having to maintain separate development, source control and build systems for targeting Windows CE.  Who is to say that the tools will even work on future versions of Windows either or even if they will live side by side with future versions of VS.  Remember this lack of support also hurts people doing unmanaged code on CE too.

MS is doing a great job of remaining silent here, the silence is already causing people to look at alternative platforms.  Without a statement of intent no business is going to invest in Windows CE development without knowing the future of the OS and the tools to develop on it.

Answer (score 0):

All recent Visual Studio versions can be installed side by side. You could upgrade now for desktop development, then when smart device support is rolled out, migrate your projects to VS2010.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/setupprerelease/thread/fce95ec7-728d-41d1-ab13-74a2fd3a4136

Answer (score 0):

I am forced to have two VS installations side by side. However, another issue - that is causing me more pain is that TFS 2010 doesn't work with VS 2008 - there is a plugin, of course, but there are many issues with it which make it unusable.

So to have source control, I have installed SVN on my machine.

Microsoft once again, has proven that they have no concern for the devs at all. Their tools don't work together, backward compatibility is not there, all of which makes their dev tools a big load of crap.

Comment: I doubt anyone is less thrilled (or more vocal with people in Redmond) with their inactivy than me, but I still their tools still beat any of the alternatives.  TFS2010 does work with Studio 08 - I do it all the time  (in fact we have a TFS 08 and a TFS 2010 server, plus Codeplex's TFS2010 server, and I use all three from Studio 2008 and Studio 2010).  You need to install the compatibility pack, but it's straightforward. The only big SxS issue I have is Studio 2005 with Platform Builder and Studio 2010, so for that I have a separate PC.

Comment: That last comment is not to defend Microsoft - their lack of inactivity for non-Phone devs is indefensible - it's just meant to point out that it's not quite as bad as your frustration might lead others to believe.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the info. I installed the plugin required for VS2008 in order to work in TFS 2010, I can open the Source Control and see the directories. However, when I try to checkin a file, TFS informs me that no changes were detected, I combed google and found zilch. As a dev, I don't have 2 months to spend on something that is supposed to make my life easier. MS problem to begin with is that they omitted Smart Device Project from VS 2010, hence making me install and set up 10,000 plugins - and take up my time. That is just my personal experience.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a "Get Specific Version" with most recent/overwrite all to reset the server mappings.  I rarely have issues from VS08 to TFS2010, and then it's usually from trying to merge code across servers

Comment: And again, yes I too am infuriated by the lacl of device support in 2010, but theres very little we can do about it but complain to deaf ears.

Comment: Another problem is that CF development is not receiving the exposure at all - it's hard to find answers online, not many devs use it. Anything that relates to it, always takes longer to research. My personal opinion is that it's on the way out which is why MS is not going to support it. They want you to move onto their Mobile framework. You could argue that it's not a good move on their part, but never the less, I now view any time spent on this application as a waste. Especially the time required to find out why TFS 2020 plugin will not check in files while used in VS 2008.

Comment: That's the problem though: I added the file to TFS, then made a change, tried to check it in. No luck. In History I only see the initial checkin. So I just installed SVN - which took me 10 minutes. VSC is supposed to make my life easier, not harder. I need the ability to revert back, merge, view history and TFS/VS are just not giving me these capabilities.

Comment: And don't get me wrong. i enjoy the project i have been working on in the last 3+ years, but it just looks like we get no love from MS.

Answer (score 0):

MS replied to that connect issue:

> Hi folks,
>
> In the first quarter of 2013, we plan to provide tooling for Visual
>   Studio 2012 to create apps for Windows Embedded Compact v.Next. We’ll
>   be announcing more details in September, including the roadmap for
>   .NET CF. You can find more details this Fall in the Windows Embedded
>   Compact website at http://www.windowsembedded.com.
>
> thanks, Doug Turnure Visual Studio PM