# VS2010 and non XNA/Silverlight Windows phone dev

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to devlop old school Windows Phone app with VS2010 ? Do I have to dowload the template as I couldn't find this kind of project when I start a new project.

I definitively want to devlop old .Net Compact Framework 3.5 app, and no XNA or Silverlight app.

Do I have to swith back to VS2008 ?

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775639/eta-on-smart-device-projects-for-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Studio 2010 doesn't have any of the project wizards or templates for general Smart Device Application programs like Studio 08 does.  Microsoft has said that they will add Smart Device programming capabilities into VS10 later, but they've not yet announced when or even what (e.g. will they support both native and managed).