# Develop for WinCE with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-ce

I have a VS2003 WinForms app running on WinCE (running on proprietary hardware so a switch is out for now) and I'd like to know if I can upgrade it to VS2010 (or 2008).  In doing so, I lose the option to deploy it to a WinCE emulator.  Is this situation just broken, or do I have options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 and non XNA/Silverlight Windows phone dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781659/vs2010-and-non-xna-silverlight-windows-phone-dev)

Answer (score 2):

VS 2008 should work ok.

VS 2010 doesn't support mobile development prior to Windows Phone 7 as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t(VS.100).aspx).

Best

Adriano

Comment: I've ported the project to VS2008, but Win CE emulator deployment doesn't seem to be an option

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, go with VS2008 (2010 won't target CF). I worked on WinCE 6 targeting .Net 2.0CF and 3.5CF. 2010 isn't an option (sadly), but at least 2008 gives you the option to use .Net 3.5 which has a lot of features I couldn't live without (linq for instance).

VS2008 is stable and a definite step up from 2005. I am fairly certain 2008 still had the emulator. We never used it as the system was beyond running on the emulator at that point, but I vaguely remember it popping up when I didn't target the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

See also:

- [ETA on smart device projects for visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775639/eta-on-smart-device-projects-for-visual-studio-2010)
- [VS2010 and non XNA/Silverlight Windows phone dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781659/vs2010-and-non-xna-silverlight-windows-phone-dev/2781698#2781698)