# Visual Studio 2010 and WinCE 5.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-ce

Is it possible to use a platform builder 5.0 SDK in visual studio 2010 for a C++ project.
I want to compile code for a specific ARM WinCE 5.0 environment and I have VS2010 at the moment.
The Microsoft website recommends visual studio 2005.  I'm currently downloading the VS2005 evaluation but I'm also a bit worried about installing this on a machine that already has vs2010 installed.
Any advise would be greatly received.

Comment: @koloko: I removed the `platform-builder` tag since you are talking about application development and not OS development.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 works just fine for Windows CE and Windows Mobile projects, too. I have both 2008 and 2012 installed side by side with no ill effects.

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2008 Express work for Windows CE?

Answer (score 4):

Read this question: [ETA on Smart Device Projects for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775639/eta-on-smart-device-projects-for-visual-studio-2010)

In short, Visual Studio 2010 does not currently support Smart Device projects so you cannot do what you want. You can use either VS2008 or VS2005 for Smart Device application development.

VS2005 and VS2010 on the same machine should not pose a problem as far as I know. You can read this [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/setupprerelease/thread/fce95ec7-728d-41d1-ab13-74a2fd3a4136) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems) in that regard.

Comment: Boy, Microsoft are all over the place when it comes to Windows Mobile devices, aren't they?

Comment: He wasn't asking about Windows Mobile, but about Windows CE. Just this little clarification shows how bad the naming scheme by Microsoft is. I can't say much about application development, but their marketing guys must improve soon.

Comment: I would *not* recommend installing VS2005 (or 2008) *after* VS2010.  Only install the tools in order of release, else you'll anger the embedded tool gods and likely have to repave.