# Developing .NET Compact Framework apps in Post-2008 Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compact-framework, windows-ce

I want to develop a Compact Framework App for a Windows CE 6.0 target device.  Can I do this with Visual Studio 2013?

If this is not possible, what would be a development environment for .net compact framework?

Comment: Wasn't VS2008 the last IDE version that included CF support?

Comment: It was.  Then it got hit by an apple.

Comment: @Marc: Not exactly.  VS2013 supports CF 3.9

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm positive this question is a duplicate, but for the life of me I can't find the original so I'll re-answer here.

Microsoft's support for Compact Framework development is not completely obvious or well documented.  It's a mixed matrix of the target version of Windows CE, the version of the Compact Framework and the version (and SKU level) of Visual Studio.

Generally speaking it comes out like this, based on your target OS:

**WEC 2013**

WEC 2013 supports *only* Compact Framework 3.9.  Assemblies targeting previous CF versions should be recompiled (though I suspect they would still run).

Compact Framework 3.9 is supported starting with Visual Studio 2012, so you must use VS2012 or later for these projects.

Unlike previous versions of the CF, CF 3.9 application development isn't provided "out of the box" in these versions of Visual Studio.  You must install an "Application Builder" SDK from the device vendor to do any CF development.

**Windows CE 7.0**

Windows CE 7.0 supports CF 3.5 or CF 2.0 applications.  Generally these devices only shipped with CF 3.5, if it was included, because 2.0 wasn't available as a catalog item in Platform Builder.

You can develop CF applications for CE 7 in Visual Studio 2008 Pro or Visual Studio 2005 Standard (CF 2.0) only.  There is no option to build using a newer version of Visual Studio for these targets, period.

Where does one get Studio 2008, you might ask?  Either through an MSDN subscription, or (and many don't know) by purchasing Platform Builder 7.

**Windows CE 6.0**

Same story as CE 7.0 above.  CF 2.0 or 3.5, using Studio 2008 Pro or Studio 2005 Standard.

**Windows CE 5.0 and Windows Mobile 5.0-6.x**

Same story as CE 7.0 with an addition.  These platforms also support CF 1.0.  For CF 1.0, using Visual Studio 2005 Standard or Visual Studio 2003 Professional.

**Windows CE 4.2**

My memory gets hazy here, since it's been a while, but IIRC you can use CF 1.0, 2.0 or [3.5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947559).  This would require Studio 2005 Standard (CF 2.0/3.5) or Studio 2003 Pro (CF 1.0)

**Windows CE 4.1**

Supports CF 1.0, using Studio 2003 Pro or eVC 4.0

**Windows CE 4.0**

Though this was called "Windows CE .NET", it actually had nothing to do with .NET outside of marketing.  It will not run CF apps of any sort.  eVB or eVC were the choices for application development

**Windows CE 3.0 and Pocket PC (original and 2003 variants)**

eVB or eVC were the development platforms.

**Windows CE 2.11 and 2.12, HPC Pro**

eVB or eVC

**Windows CE 2.0, PsPC**

(Yes, my memory goes back this far)
eVB, eVC or the Visual Basic 6.0 Toolkit for Windows CE, depending on when you came into it

Comment: With a later service pack, CF 3.5 was supported on the CE 4.2 devices.  There were 6 months there though that kind of sucked having to develop for both CF 2 and CF 3.5 on some of our software.

Comment: Hola, Amigo! I think the duplicate post you quoted at the top is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22173057/153923

Answer (score 9):

If targeting Windows CE/Mobile 5-6.5 then the last version to support .NET CF was Visual Studio 2008 and so generally speaking apps for .NET CF must be developed in that.

There is however a plugin for Visual Studio 2013 (required Visual Studio 2008 Installed) to allow development of .NET CF apps but its not free:

http://ifactr.com/platform/modernization-framework/visual-studio-2013-compact-framework-plugin

Comment: And that add-in uses the Studio 2008 compiler, so you still have to have Studio 2008 installed.

Comment: @ctacke I've played around with the plugin some, and while it does let you work with CF in VS2013, it doesn't work with the forms designer, so you're limited to using it for libraries.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the statement that "the last version to support .NET CF was Visual Studio 2008 and so generally speaking apps for .NET CF must be developed in that." Is there a reference to this on MSDN?

Comment: Please note my answer refers to Windows Mobile 5-6.5 development and therefore .NET CF 2 - 3.5

As stated by tcarvin .NET CF 3.9 can be developed in VS 2012/2013 but these will not work on Windows CE 5 or Mobile 5-6.5

Answer (score 5):

It is alwyas best to go to the source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197932.aspx

A quick summary:

> Get started developing for Windows Embedded Compact in Visual Studio
>   (Compact 2013)
>
> You can develop your .NET Compact Framework 3.9 or Visual C++ apps
>   from within Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2012 Professional,
>   Premium, and Ultimate editions. When you install Application Builder
>   and the SDK provided for the version of Windows Embedded Compact
>   Edition you are targeting, the SDK provides Visual Studio project
>   templates and Application Builder provides the ability to deploy your
>   apps from Visual Studio to a device or virtual machine for debugging
>   and testing.

---

And if you are targeting earlier devices that are still running Windows Mobile 6.5 or earlier, or Windows CE devices running Windows Embedded Compact 7 or earlier, you will need to use the tried-and-true Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: While the OP did not specify it is worth noting that this is only for Windows Embedded Compact 2013 operating system not Windows CE/Mobile 6.5 (as I, perhaps wrongly, assumed).