# Windows CE 7 Emulator and Programming

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

My company is thinking of switching to these handheld units: https://www.barcodesinc.com/motorola/part-mc32n0-gi4hcheia.htm#specs
They run off of Windows Embedded Compact 7. I have been tasked with programming an inventory management solution. I do have C# .NET experience, but no experience with Compact Framework(CF), so I have a few questions.

1. Do I have to use VS 2012 with CF 3.9 or can I use a newer version of VS?
2. Is there an emulator that could run Embedded Compact so that I could give a demo of the software without buying the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use Visual Studio 2008, I'm afraid.

As for getting an emulator running try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200348(v=winembedded.70).aspx

Source: I'm a mobile dev thats worked on CE 5, WM 6 and WM 6.5 (but not 7)

(Just as a side opinion, CE is dead/dying. And it's pretty horrible to work on/support as a developer. GOOD LUCK!)

Comment: This was an answer from 2015. I'm coming from the future, 2023, and still people using Windows CE 

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE 7.0 only supports .NET CF 2.0 and 3.5, and the latest Visual Studio version that will work is VS2008.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24247918/5181033) gives a great overview of which Windows CE, .NET Compact Framework and Visual Studio versions go together.

Which emulator to use depends on your desktop environment:

- If you are on Windows 7, the way to go is [Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4580).
- On newer versions of desktop Windows you can use Hyper-V.

There's an emulator [Getting Started guide here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200348.aspx). It's written for WEC2013, but will work for CE7.0 as well.