# IDE for Compact Framework 3.5 on Windows CE 6

Tags: c#, .net, ide, compact-framework, windows-ce

We have some applications running on data reader devices with windows CE 6.0.
These apps was created with [genexus](http://www.genexus.com) generating C# / .Net Compact Framework 3.5

Genexus will not support this anymore and I´m looking for alternatives to rewrite these apps.

First, off course, i thought about Microsoft, but i would have to use visual studio 2008 (too old, my devices are also, but...).
Than i thought about SharpDevelop, but Compact Framework was dropped in version 4.

Does anyone know an alternative to develop C# for Windows CE 6.0?

Comment: What, specifically, is keeping you from using Visual Studio 2008?  What makes it "too old"?  Missing features that you can't live without?  If so, state what features because those are part of your requirements for the "newer" IDE you're looking for.

Comment: If necessary, i will use vs2008. But I rather to save money... and also... many data reader are not using windows CE anymore. So i´m looking for a "future proof" solution, like nsbasic and genexus does, but they dropped winCE support.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241978/developing-net-compact-framework-apps-in-post-2008-visual-studio/24247918#24247918. To my knowledge there is no viable alternative to VS2008 for CE6 devices

Comment: I agree with Carsten Hansen - you probably should change your question and specify VS2008 is "too expensive" instead of "too old" because there most probably won't be any newer IDE's that beat VS2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 (or 2005) is your only option and that's simply never going to change.  Microsoft abandoned the Compact Framework starting in about 2010 and completely in about 2015.  Windows CE itself has effectively been abandoned as well.  There's simply no market for anyone else to even try to make an IDE for development for systems that have zero future.