# program windows CE in c# 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-ce

is their way to developing an application for windows ce device? I have a barcode scanner device with an OS of windows ce and I only have a visual studio 2012. If we buy the 2008 version its only add to cost of development and its possible we only use that in once. If not possible is there any free PL out there that can be use?

Answer (score 0):

The development environment available depends on the version of Windows CE that runs on the scanner.

So you'll need to determine the Windows CE version, and then take a look at this page: [Developing .NET Compact Framework apps in Post-2008 Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241978/developing-net-compact-framework-apps-in-post-2008-visual-studio)