# Windows CE 5.0 development environment

Tags: windows-ce, sql-server-ce

I have to create an application using a Datalogic mobile device that uses Windows CE 5.0

I need a database that should work with Windows CE 5.0 and in addition can also be used in a normal Windows desktop OS (XP, Windows 7 ...)

So I was thinking that I should use Visual Studio 2008, C++ as programming language, SQL Server CE as database and SQL Server 2008 as the database manager.

Are these good choices or should I choose something else?

I won't use Visual Studio 2010 because it seems that it doesn't support Windows CE 5.0: [ETA on Smart Device Projects for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775639/eta-on-smart-device-projects-for-visual-studio-2010)

Also any resources recommendation for learning to program Windows CE 5.0 applications is more than welcome, this would be my first application using mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to do the same I'd choose:

- Studio 2008
- Compact Framework (C#) 3.5 for the UI, data access, etc.
- C/C++ only if absolutely necessary and only for those parts that require it
- SQL Compact for the on-device storage (the data files work on the desktop as-is)

Not sure why you need full-up SQL Server - SQL Compact works on the desktop too, so unless you need the larger servies and features of Server it's probably unnecessary.  If you do need it, the plus is that Management Studio can directly open SQL Compact files and Server can use them for replication, etc.

Obviously your skill set might drive some of the requirements other ways, but the above is what I would use because I've done a lot of project with those technologies and they've proven to be fast to deliver, provide better than acceptable performance, allow ease of extensibility and have a low cost to maintain.