# How to start developing an application on Windows CE?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-ce, motorola

I'm new to the CE environment, I have to create an application for a mobile computer with a barcode scanne that uses Windows CE 5.0  (***motorola mc3000***)

I was thinking that I should use Visual Studio 2008 because it seems that neither VS2010 and VS2012 doesn't support Windows CE 5.0  :  [ETA on Smart Device Projects for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775639/eta-on-smart-device-projects-for-visual-studio-2010)

I have never used CE before and I have searched a lot for useful tutorials to help me in my task, but unfortunately it was with no result.

Does any one know any good tutoriel to help me to make a good start knowing that I'm using windows 7 ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tutorial for Visual Studio 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446906.aspx)

The tutorial should work for 2003/2005. 2008 probably has support for Windows 6.0 rather than 5.0
The SDK's documentation should include information about accessing the Motorola camera.

Comment: Really thx ^_^ !!!

but I have a litle problem testing with a real device; like I mentioned before, I will work with a Motorola Mc3000 device and I don't know how to connect and test on it. Do you know about any tutoriel to help me with this .. ?  thank you in advance